# how to label a binarized image?

Tags: image-processing, background-subtraction

please help me to segment a image in binary image...
more clearly,
i got a image from background subtraction, which is binary...means, the object area is of white color and non object object is black..now problem is how to label that white area? 
i m using c#.net.

Comment: Please provide more information. Programming language, image format, and what do you mean by "label"?

Comment: image is converted into gray matrix of type float.now label means put any color say red... to boundary of object.

Answer (score 4):

If by "label the white area" you just mean create a bucket with a label (e.g., "TheObject") and add all the connected white pixels to it, then the most straightforward way is the so-called "[sequential algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction)".

The two-pass algorithm described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling) is also easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

using python, you will find the tools you need at:
[http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas](http://mahotas)

under java use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) with Landini's morphological plugins